# PowerShell DSC Pull and Push Mode Together

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, dsc

I am using PowerShell 4.0 and configured a DSC Pull Server. Few clients are connected to the Pull Server and those are getting configurations properly. Below is the LCM details in a client machine:
 [image]

However, there are some times we would like to push a configuration to these clients. When I try to push, it is successful and the RefershMode gets changed to PUSH and all other settings are as it was before. Now from now onwards I don’t get any configuration from the Pull server anymore. Again I needed to change the mode to PUSH and it works fine.

Can both Pull and Push modes can be configured in the same client machine ? Will those work together ?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, these modes cannot exist on the same machine; it's one or the other.

<s>I have to question why you would want to do this. Presumably, if a machine is already in a Pull configuration, then the configuration you want to Push onto it must be different from what's on the Pull server. If that's the case, why would you want to then revert to Pull which would completely override the Push configuration?</s>

Based on your comment, I would recommend that you change the configuration on the Pull server for the node(s) when you want to make changes. The process of generating the MOF files and the checksum files and then copying them to the Pull server can be automated. You can then use:

```psh
Invoke-CimMethod -Namespace root/Microsoft/Windows/DesiredStateConfiguration –ClassName MSFT_DSCLocalConfigurationManager -MethodName PerformRequiredConfigurationChecks -Arg @{Flags = [System.UInt32]1 } -ComputerName $targetNode
```

to force the Node to pull and re-apply configuration.

Comment: Actually we are having a set of servers (which we use for testing deployment) where we want to keep a specific set of softwares installed and configuration. Thats why we created the Pull server and keeping the configuration. However, while testing the deployment we generally push the DSC configuration. Thats why I wanted to check if both mode can exists together.

Comment: Also I can see I can provide only one ConfigurationID for a client. Can I get the configurations partially from different resources after adding multiple ConfigurationID ?

Comment: I have edited the answer to address your first comment (though it  may not be what you were looking for). As for partial configurations, those are not available until PowerShell v5.0 (there are many really nice improvements coming to DSC in v5), but that is in technical preview right now, so you probably do not want to use it in production yet.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It makes sense. I was checking on Partial configuration but didn't get much. Am I will be able to achieve my scenario  using PS 5.0 DSC Partial Configuration ?

Comment: In v5 you are actually able to specify the refresh mode (Push/Pull) on an individual configuration, so it may help with that. There is support for multiple Pull servers as well, and with partials you may be able to split it up exactly the way you want. There are also separate IDs for nodes and configuration in that version. I don't fully know your scenario so I can't say for sure whether v5 will do everything you want. You can [download it and evaluate it](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46889) right now though.